# How to remove block text between 2 patterns?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have the following text in my file

```
---BEGIN TEXT---
any text1
anytext2
anytext3
---END TEXT---
---BEGIN TEXT---
any text4
any text5
---END TEXT---
```

I want to remove the **2nd** text block from `"---BEGIN TEXT---"` to `"---END TEXT---"`

How I can make that with a linux command

So my file will contains only:

```
---BEGIN TEXT---
any text1
anytext2
anytext3
---END TEXT---
```

I know how to remove the 1st block with the following command:

```
sed -n '/BEGIN TEXT/,/END TEXT/{p;/PAT2/q}' file.txt
```

How I can modify my `sed` comand to remove the 2nd part and not the first part? or use another command like `awk` ?

Comment: if there are no further blocks, you can reverse the input file, remove first block and then reverse again... awk would be better suited here

Comment: Can there be text before, after and in the middle of these 2 blocks?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a modified sample for a generic solution

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foobaz
---BEGIN TEXT---
block 1
any text
---END TEXT---
1234567
---BEGIN TEXT---
block 2
any text
---END TEXT---
helloworld
---BEGIN TEXT---
block 3
any text
---END TEXT---
42424242
```

To remove only the second block:

```
$ awk -v b=2 '/BEGIN TEXT/{f=1; c++} !(f && c==b); /END TEXT/{f=0}' ip.txt 
foobaz
---BEGIN TEXT---
block 1
any text
---END TEXT---
1234567
helloworld
---BEGIN TEXT---
block 3
any text
---END TEXT---
42424242
```

- `-v b=2` the block to be removed
- `/BEGIN TEXT/{f=1; c++}` set flag and increment counter when starting regex is matched
- `/END TEXT/{f=0}` clear flag for ending regex
- `!(f && c==b)` don't print input record if flag is set and it is the block specified by `b` variable

Further reading:

- [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

  - the solution here is a variation on `awk '/PAT1/{flag=1} flag; /PAT2/{flag=0}'` which is explained in the linked Q&A
- [my tutorial on dealing with specific blocks](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/gnu_awk.md#specific-blocks)

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='---END TEXT---\n' '{ORS=RT} NR==1' file
---BEGIN TEXT---
any text1
anytext2
anytext3
---END TEXT---

$ awk -v RS='---END TEXT---\n' '{ORS=RT} NR!=1' file
---BEGIN TEXT---
any text4
any text5
---END TEXT---

$ awk -v RS='---END TEXT---\n' '{ORS=RT} NR==2' file
---BEGIN TEXT---
any text4
any text5
---END TEXT---
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `sed` you can use `awk`:

```
awk '/BEGIN TEXT/{found++} found==1{print $0}' yourfile
```

`awk` processes files line by line. So here we test to see if the current line has the `BEGIN TEXT` in it. If it does, we bump the `found` variable by 1. In the next block we print the line `print $0` if the `found` variable is equal to 1.

If the file is large and we want to stop processing after `found` is greater than 1 we can add an additional block to exit

```
awk '/BEGIN TEXT/{found++} found==1{print $0} found>1{exit 0}' yourfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk and multi-line record:

```
awk -v RS='---END TEXT---' 'NR==1{print $0 RT}' file
```

`RS` is the record separator, set to the end of the block.

`NR` is the number of record. In this case we only want the first one.

`RT` is the record terminator that store the record seperator of the current record, and is printed together with the wanted block.

Comment: That will output a leading blank line if/when you want to print any but the first block.

Answer (score 0):

simplistically, `sed -i '/---END TEXT---/q;' txtfile` though I don't think that's actually the answer you wanted.

You *could* write a more complex sed script that does a lot of hold and pattern space manipulation, but meh.

If what you specifically wanted was to exclude the second set, here's a way using just bash. Not better than the awk answers, but I like to contribute variety.

```
c=0; while read line; do [[ "$line" = "---BEGIN TEXT---" ]] && (( c++ )); (( c != 2 )) && echo "$line"; done <txt
```

or, formatted -

```
c=0
while read line
do [[ "$line" = "---BEGIN TEXT---" ]] && (( c++ ))
   (( c != 2 )) && echo "$line"
done < txtfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/---BEGIN/{:a;N;/^---END/M!ba;x;s/^/x/;/^x{2}$/{x;d};x}' file
```

Gather up the lines between `---BEGIN` and `---END` and then increment a counter in the hold space (HS). If the counter is 2 delete the collection otherwise print as normal.